# Remove Bootstrap's validation icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

### Explanation

I'm trying to remove these [Bootstrap's validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#validation) icons ("x" and "check"), but I've look into everything and can't find where it is.

### Code

You can also see in it this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/at9enbmo/).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="was-validated">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" required>
      <option value="">Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom select feedback</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can simply remove the icon by by setting the `background` property to `none` for that specific CSS class/pseudo-class

```
.was-validated .custom-select:valid {
  background-image: none;
}


.was-validated .custom-select:invalid {
  background-image: none;
}
```

If you would like to remove the validation icons, but retain the arrow icons on the select input, it can be achieved by setting the `background` to the following

```
.was-validated .custom-select:invalid {
     background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3e%3cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") no-repeat right .75rem center/8px 10px;
}
```

**Update for bootstrap 4:**

Setting the background image to none for the particular selector retained the background color and the dropdown button.

```
.form-control.is-invalid{
    background-image: none;
}
```

**Update for those working with Bootstrap's SASS/SCSS:**

Please refer to [PCalouche](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56444581/10959940)'s excellent answer!

Comment: It doesn't work in my case because I need the `background` to show. If it disappears, it'll reveal the color behind it.

Comment: Sorry, may I know what background are you referring to? How does it look like? I have just made the edits, such that the arrow icons wont disappear

Comment: I manage to work around with your answer and come to what I needed. All I had to do was to set `background-image: none;`, instead of all the `background`. I'll accept your answer because you answered first, but could you please edit it with the code above?

Answer (score 40):

If you are compiling BootStrap's SCSS you can include this before you import bootstrap.scss:

```
$enable-validation-icons: false;
```

Comment: How did you know this? :o

Comment: If installing boostrap via npm it includes a scss/_variables.scss file with lots of things you can override.  Glad this helped.

Comment: This is the simplest and correct method of disabling validation icons. Simply remove it to enable.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 4:

```html
.form-control.is-valid,
.form-control.is-invalid {
    background-image: none;
    padding-right: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but for input fields with `type=date`. I had to add `padding-right: 0.75em;` so that the calender icon has the same padding as before and does not oddly move.

CSS:

```
/* remove validation icons */
.form-control.is-invalid, .was-validated .form-control:invalid {
    background-image: none !important;
    border-color: #ced4da;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
}

.form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    background-image: none !important;
    border-color: #ced4da;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom-select.is-invalid, .was-validated .custom-select:valid,.custom-select.is-invalid, .was-validated .custom-select:invalid {
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3e%3cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") no-repeat right .75rem center/8px 10px,url("data:image/vg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%2328a745' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") no-repeat center right 1.75rem/1.125rem 1.125rem !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="was-validated">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="custom-select" required>
      <option value="">Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom select feedback</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/therowf/bvts06dq/19/)

Comment: It doesn't work in my case because I need the `background` to show. If it disappears, it'll reveal the color behind it.

Comment: I have not removed the background just changed. Please see the correction. @Luiz

Comment: As your answer was similar to [wentjun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622876/5802882), the same thing I commented in his answer applies to yours. Since I can only accept one answer, I'll upvote yours, but could you please edit your code with `background-image: none;`?

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

remove this code `, error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'` in `simple_form_bootstrap.rb`